# Google Apps Script how to get "live" data?

Tags: google-apps-script, live

If I make a simple GAS script logging data from a sheet in an infinite loop it will always log the value that was in the sheet when the script started, even if I manually change it.
 How to make the script get the manually updated ("live") data ?

**This is not happening if the data is in the same doc** but I really need this to set a live "flag".

If it cannot be done , what other ***suggestions for a live "flag"*** used by multiple scripts do you have ***?***

EDIT:
I added some sample code for clarity, it's a pretty basic code though

```
       function test(){
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1N8_b1...6srPfYzhI')
  var sh = SS.getSheetByName('Sheet5')
  var count = 0
  while(count<25){
    count += 1
    Utilities.sleep(500)
    Logger.log(sh.getRange("A1").getValue())
    }
  }
```

The output when I run this in log was the initial text present in sheet at the start of running the script, "aaa" written 25 times, even though in the time it was running I changed "aaa" to many other texts during the run time.

Comment: Do you have some code to share as an example of what you are doing? [mcve]

Comment: added. Again, just to remember the problem only exists when it's a different doc. In the same doc the data is live.

Comment: If you do this your script is going to exceed the 6 minute time limit and  it will be stopped and you will receive and error.

Comment: it was just a demonstrative script. But ok, changing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Read this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()).

```
function testquestion()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  var count = 0
  while(count<25)
  {
    count+=1;
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    Logger.log(sh.getRange("A1").getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much . I can't believe I didn't notice that function yet :D